# Png buffer Uint8Array is not displayed using FIleReader in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, blob, png

So I have a mysql database with a longblob column, using express i send the already uploaded image to the front-end using express and react and axios. In React I try to create a FileReader, read the buffer and display the image using a state for the src of the image, code for everything is below.

The sent data of the image:
(bannerImage here is the File itself)

```
const bannerImage = eventBanner;
const bannerImageFormData = new FormData();
if (bannerImage) {
  bannerImageFormData.set(
    "bannerImage",
    bannerImage,
    values.eventId
  );
  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: WEBSITE_URL + "bannerImage",
    data: bannerImageFormData,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
  })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    .finally(() => {
      window.location.reload();
    });
}
```

The upload for the image:

```
app.post(
  "/bannerImage/",
  multer().single("bannerImage"),
  function (request, response) {
    try {
      const file = request.file.buffer;
        let blobData = [
        request.file.originalname + "_image",
        1,
        file,
    ];
    let blobSql = `INSERT INTO blobstore(id, counter, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`;
    con.query(blobSql, blobData);
      response.send({ code: 200 });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      response.send({ code: 400, failed: "error occurred" });
    }
  }
);
```

so now the image is stored in the database in a longblob

Now i want to get the file and display it:

```
app.get("/events", function (request, response) {
  try {
    let sql = `SELECT *
                   FROM event`;
    let ress = [];
    let blobs = [];
    let blobSql = `SELECT *
                       FROM blobstore`;
    con.query(blobSql, (error, results, fields) => {
      blobs = results;
    });
    con.query(sql, (error, results, fields) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        const row = results[i];
        let correctBlobValue = "";
    let bannerImage = "";
        for (let j = 0; j < blobs.length; j++) {
          const blobRow = blobs[j];
          if (blobRow.id === row.id) {
            correctBlobValue = blobRow.value.toString("utf-8");
          }
    else if(row.id + "_image" === blobRow.id){
        bannerImage = blobRow.value;
      }
        }
    let element = {
          id: row.id,
          name: row.name,
          date: row.date,
      text: correctBlobValue,
          type: row.type,
          ticketLink: row.ticketlink,
      bannerImage: bannerImage,
        };
        ress.push(element);
      }
    response.set('Content-Type', 'image/png');
        response.send(ress);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    response.send({ code: 400, failed: "error occurred" });
  }
});
```

It is only relevant that i get the correct image and return the stored Blob using Content-Type image/png i think.

Now i want to display the image (note that imageDataUrl is a react state)

```
  useMemo(() => {
    if (eventDetails && eventDetails.bannerImage) {
      const blob = new Blob([eventDetails.bannerImage.data], {
        type: "image/png",
      }); // Adjust type as needed
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
        const result = reader.result as string;
        setImageDataUrl(result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    }
  }, [eventDetails]);
```

and the image itself

```
<img className={"eventBanner"} src={imageDataUrl} alt={"banner"} />
```

So for some reason this does not display the image even though the file Reader returns a correctly encoded base64 string like this:

'data:image/png;base64,MTM3LDgwLDc4LDcxLD....'

For some reason this base64 encoded string also is quite larger than the uploaded image file ( which is a png of course )